# MySQL - Correct Way to Perform Subtraction on Two Select Statements

Tags: mysql

I have two select statements which return a rainfall total from 7am yesterday and 7am today.

```
SELECT RainCounter FROM `monthly_new` WHERE LogDateTime = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 17 hour
SELECT RainCounter FROM `monthly_new` WHERE LogDateTime = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 hour
```

The first value will always be less than or equal to the second, but never greater.

I am trying to figure out how to turn this into one statement where I can select both values, subtract the first from the second, and return the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract the result of subqueries in the `SELECT` part of a wrapping query (if those subqueries return exactly one value each):

`SELECT (subquery) - (subquery)`

In your case:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT RainCounter FROM `monthly_new` WHERE LogDateTime = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 hour) - (SELECT RainCounter FROM `monthly_new` WHERE LogDateTime = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 17 hour)
```